# ASA5505 slow downstream, fast upstream on VDSL PPPoE

Tags: cisco-asa

We have recently switched our ADSL2+ connection for a VDSL Connection in our office.

The *only* configuration change I have made to the Cisco ASA for this change, was to change the username/password on the PPPoE settings for the `outside` interface, change the MTU to 1492 and swap the modems on the physical interface.

I'm getting 10+Mbps upload speed, as I would expect, but our *download* speed seems to jump around anywhere between 1 and 5Mbps, and is anything but stable, and never gets anywhere near to the speed it should be.

When I bypass the ASA and go direct to the modem, I get the full download speed in both directions. When the ISP monitored our session at the first hop, they were only seeing 1-5Mbps of traffic and nothing dropped from any queues.

The Smartnet expired *three* days ago and accounts did not pay for the renewal, so while that mess is sorted out I'm hoping someone can give me some pointers on where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more discussions with the ISP, it turns out that they had to re-do the connection at the MDF in the basement over the weekend. The modem got a terrible line sync during that maintenance and never re-negotiated the sync speed, even during the config changes I made over the last few days.

A power cycle on the modem got the sync speed back to 110/110 in both directions and everything is behaving normally now.

Comment: That again adds validity to the stereotypical first line support request: *have you restarted the PC? modem? router?* etc....